# Why Qt5 warns about a miisng signal, while it uses the signal?

Tags: qt5, signals-slots

I use the line

```
connect(ui->Ysim, SIGNAL(ui->Ysim->StartButton_Get()->click()),
 this,SLOT(on_startButton_clicked()));
```

It works fine, the debugger takes me to the on_clicked method.However, I receive the message that

```
 QObject::connect: No such signal
```

Do I need to provide another syntax? Or ho to get rid of the warning? (I guess it has some reason)

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Please post the complete error message verbatim -- it should include the name/spec of the signal in question.  Also, you should really be using the [new signal/slot syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).  It will catch obvious issues like this at compile time.